# How to make horizontal paging without vertical paging in UIScrollView

Tags: iphone, uiscrollview, paging

I am making digital comic now.
My application has horizontal paging when without zooming.
But when zooming, picture's height is over the screen height.
So application has vertical paging.

But I don't need vertical paging.
i want to make horizontal paging without vertical paging during zooiming.

Please teach me.

Comment: Can be done with one scroll view:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10478586/uiscrollview-paging-in-single-direction/10480071#10480071

Answer (score 13):

It's really simple. As your friend suggested, you will need AT LEAST two `UIScrollView`. You will need one `UIScrollView` for the horizontal (i.e. paging), and you will need one `UIScrollView` for *each* page. The key points are (let's name them `scrollHorizontal` and `scrollVertical`):

- `scrollHorizontal.frame.height` must equal `scrollHorizontal.contentSize.height` (otherwise, you will end up with vertical paging)
- `scrollVertical`: first, you will have one of this for each page. The frame width and `contentSize.width` should match and make sense w.r.t. the width of a page (in your `scrollHorizontal`). You should of course have the frame height be no more than `scrollHorizontal.contentSize.height`.

Sample code:

```
UIScrollView scrollHorizontal = [[UIScrollView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, self.view.bounds.size.width, self.view.bounds.size.height)];

scrollHorizontal.pagingEnabled = YES;
scrollHorizontal.directionalLockEnabled = YES; // not needed but helpful

// Now let's create each page

UIScrollView *scrollPage1 = [[UIScrollView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, self.view.bounds.size.width, self.view.bounds.size.height)];

[scrollPage1 addSubview:theContentViewForPage1];

scrollPage1.contentSize = CGSizeMake(self.view.bounds.size.width, theContentViewForPage1.bounds.size.height);

// Add page to scrollHorizontal

[scrollHorizontal addSubview:scrollPage1];
[scrollPage1 release];

//...add more pages (REMEMBER to set the scroll view's frame.origin.x accordingly for each additional page)

// Set the scrollHoriztonal content size
scrollView.contentSize = CGSizeMake(self.view.bounds.size.width*NUMBER_OF_PAGES, self.view.bounds.size.height);

// Now add the scrollview to self.view; or even self.view = scrollHorizontal, etc.
```

Comment: I've been trying to figure out something similar and this answer conpletly did it.  Thank you so much

Answer (score -1):

There technically is no such thing as vertical paging, only horizontal as of right now for the standard API.  Up/down is scrolling, and paging left/right is a little different.

You should be able to disable vertical scrolling within Interface Builder after selecting the uiscrollview and editing its properties within the inspector window.

Answer (score -1):

You can dynamically set the `pagingEnabled` to `NO` when the user zooms in, and then set it back to `YES` when they zoom out.

Check out the [docs](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/uikit/reference/UIScrollViewDelegate_Protocol/Reference/UIScrollViewDelegate.html) for `UIScrollViewDelegate` to learn how to detect zooming.

Comment: Thank you.But it is not enough, because I need horizontal paging during zooming.I want to only switch off paging of vertical.
But I knew I can't turn off paging of vertical.
So someone tell me advice.
He said it is able to turn off vertical paging using 2 scrollView.
One is whole pages with pagingEnabled=NO;
Another one is only one page with pagingEnabled=YES;
But my sample doesn't work correctly.
Anyone please help me.